# Why ListView Not Showing Items ON WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to Display the List View Values On WPF APP, but I only able to show the headers, on the following is the very simple code:

```
 public class Ticket 
    {
        public string Descrption { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Ticket()
        {    
        }           
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllTasks}" Margin="34,30,69,65">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Descrption}" Header="Ticket" Width="150"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" Width="50"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>



public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Ticket> AllTasks { get; set; }
        public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AllTasks = new List<Ticket>();           

            Ticket ticket2 = new Ticket();
            ticket2.Descrption = "test";
            ticket2.Status = "To Do";
            AllTasks.Add(ticket2);

            Ticket ticket3 = new Ticket();
            ticket3.Descrption = "New Ticket";
            ticket3.Status = "In Progress";

            AllTasks.Add(ticket3);

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

The UI appearing like the follwing image:

[image]

Comment: How should the expected result look like? A List or a DataGrid?

Comment: ticekt2 and ticke3 rows value must displaying in listview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF data binding only works with public properties:

```
public List<Ticket> AllTasks { get; set; }
```

The property should also be readonly (or fire a property change notification):

```
public List<Ticket> AllTasks { get; } = new List<Ticket>();
```

In case you want to add or remove elements after setting the view's DataContext, use an ObservableCollection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Ticket> AllTasks { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<Ticket>();
```